# How to place minifigure legs into normal LDD bricks, like a 1x2 brick?

Tags: building, minifigures, ldd

Let me clear up the confusion surrounding this question to the best of my abilities

I'm currently in the final steps of finishing of a mech project I started some time back, finishing now at the hands, literally, of the mech. I have decided to use minifigure pants/legs (the bottom section of the minifigure) as the figure aspect of the mech. This mech is in LDD.

What I want to do is place this brick

[image]

into this brick in LDD

[image]

How can I go about doing this in LDD?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I see what you mean...  Friggin' annoying!  Can't do it Stud.io Ver 1.0 (157) either.  I haven't installed Stud.io 2.0 yet, to see if it's possible in the upgrade.

Hmm...  You could... Just create a work-a-round that could potentially make your model a little more unique.

These program issues are frustrating, but they're fun when they force us to think of an alternative.

Here, try these *Mech Fisticuff Gauntlets*. The pictures look like nonsense, so let me explain the layout.

**FRONT VIEW.**
[image]

It reads loosely in columns from left to right.  Your new fist configuration build are the 4th and 5th Columns.

- 1st Column: Dark Gray 1x2 brick = Height 3 Plates.
- 2nd Column: Blue MiniFig Legs = Height 5 plates.
- 3rd Column: The total height of Legs and 1x2 brick.  = 8 plates high.
  LDD won't let us stack a 1x2 brick on to leg stalk.
- 4th Column: Our alternate fist, fingers fully extended.  (Note: It
  will be an unnoticeable 1/2 plate shorter then your original fists.
- 5th Column: Our alternate fist, fingers curled up, forming a Left
  fist.
- 6th loose splatter pieces: Four individual pieces to our fist recipe.

  1. 93062 Skeleton Leg.
  2. 26047 Modified 1 x 1 Rounded with Handle.
  3. 99780 1 x 2 - 1 x 2 Inverted.
  4. 15573 Modified 1 x 2 with 1 Stud with Groove and Bottom Stud
       Holder (Jumper).
- 7th Pointing Hand of Prime.

**Final Note**: *LEGO* may not have those Skeleton legs in the colors we want in real life, but look through for other minifig leg or hinge+1x1 plate combination to get your Mech finger/knuckles right.

**EDIT**=>[***HERE***](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zWfjf_vJFfsB8urPykD07347eYPUeVXq/view?usp=sharing) For reals. You can download my LDD file from my Google Drive, and import the alternate into your build file in LDD.  Save you some time.

**BACK VIEW.**
[image]

**SICK VIEW.**
[image]

Comment: That third solution with the skeleton legs is a very tempting solution to this dilemma I'm having. I might just pull the trigger on this one, but I am waiting for Stud.io 2.0+ to finish downloading before I do anything I might regret. Thanks for answering!

Comment: Updated the answer to add a LDD file to import into your model.  Later!

Comment: Sorry for the late comment. You really didn't have to upload an LDD file. I would think the design is pretty straight forward. But nonetheless I do appreciate the help! Marked as Answer!